# How to acces Team Foundation Server 2015 configured on local client PC, from other pc connected to that wifi network from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio

I have installed and configured Team Foundation Server 2015 on my client laptop. And i have created one team project from Visual Studio 2015 Team explorer. So my TFS 2015 is installed on one laptop.

Can someone explain me step by step on How to access team project from TFS 2015 configured on one laptop from other laptop connected to the same wi-fi network as laptop with TFS?

Answer (score 0):

You just access http://laptopWithTFS:8080/tfs.

If you are unable to access the web access then you will need to open the Windows Firewall on LaptopWithTFS for port 8080.

http://windows.microsoft.com/windows-8/Windows-Firewall-from-start-to-finish

Once open and you can access via the web you can:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Click Team | Connect to Team Foundation
3. Add your new server
4. Connect

**However running TFS in this way for anything other than experimentation is nuts.**

You would be much better getting an account at http://tfs.visualstudio.com and using Visual Studio Team services (TFS Online).